# Good example code for Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to learn objective-c and am having a hard time coming from (java / C#). Does anyone have sample code that explains how the inner workings of objective-c work? I found a couple tutorials (below) but I'd like to start working through some examples that are a little more complex than "hello world".

http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/

http://www.otierney.net/objective-c.html

http://mobileappmastery.com/objective-c-tutorial/

Comment: I would get a book from the library.

Comment: Step 1: It's called “Objective-C”, not “objective C”. If you really want to see how the internals of Objective-C work, I'd read [The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/ObjC.pdf}), and then read the [documentation for the Objective-C Runtime](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html). That should give you a pretty thorough understanding of both the surface-structure of the language and its implementation.

Comment: Is this really a question where's there is going to be one best answer? Seems like this would be a better fit as a community wiki question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ray Wenderlich has some very good tutorials.  His [Simple iPhone App Tutotial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-1) is in 3 parts.  If you follow it step by step, it will give you a great overview on how an iOS app works.  Once you complete it, you can follow is more complex tutorials.  Good luck.

Comment: I like this answer because it's somewhat complex enough for a beginner to understand many of the cocoa facets without being too difficult.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend a decent book, too: it's a complex language, and unless you get an end-to-end grounding in its peculiarities (and there are a number of them), you're almost certain to confuse yourself at some point. (There are definitely more opportunities to confuse yourself with Objective-C than C++, in my opinion...)

A book I like a lot is "Learning Objective-C 2.0", by Robert Clair, published by Addison-Wesley...

Comment: I disagree. It's a simple language. It just comes with big frameworks.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for example working code, I've been using two main source -

- [Cocoa Controls](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/) - for specific UI elements
- [Binpress](http://www.binpress.com) - for complete applications and SDKs

For me, the most effective way to learn is by going over actual working code from real applications, instead of mock code used in tutorials and very basic examples. Maybe it's because I already have background in other languages and don't need to cover the basics.